# special characters in http_proxy environment variable

Tags: linux, bash, proxy, command-line-interface

What is the correct format using special characters in http_proxy environment variable?
Or to be mor specific, what to do with special characters in username or password when authenticate to http proxy on the command line.

Comment: What do you mean by "special characters"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, the complete format is:

```
http_proxy='http://user:pass@server:port/'
```

Every special character in username and password must not conflict with the characters used in the above format AND must be URL compliant.

Here is an example:

```
Domain: ADMIN DOM
User:   my@email.address  
PW:     a%b(c/x@y z
Server: proxy.server.at
Port:   8080
```

becomes:

```
'http://ADMIN%20DOM\my%40email.address:a%25b(c%2Fx%40y%20z@proxy.server.at:8080/'
```

And to prevent bash interpretation of any character always use single-quotes.

You can set this system wide in /etc/environment like this:

```
http_proxy='http://ADMIN%20DOM\my%40email.address:a%25b(c%2Fx%40y%20z@proxy.server.at:8080/'
```

Easy URL encoding/decoding:
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=url+encode+a%25b%28c%2Fx%40y+z&kl=at-de
or
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=url+escaping

Answer (score 1):

**Even more simple and Reliable!**

**General Syntax:**

```
sudo {http,https,ftp}_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy_url/_proxyip>:<port>/ wget --timeout=5 --no-check-certificate http://<website_url>
```

**Example:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# sudo {http,https,ftp}_proxy=http://username:password-123@proxy.example.com:6050/ wget --timeout=5 --no-check-certificate http://google.com
```

**{http,https,ftp}_proxy**   -> http, https, ftp urls. Seperated by comma.

**--timeout=5**  -> Connection to keep alive in seconds.

**-no-check-certificate**  -> Ignore SSL / Certificate Verification.

**--spider**  -> If you want to test the connectivity without downloading the file.

**Notes:**

**Online Converter:**

Replace special characters with its equivalent hexadecimal unicode. 
For a list of unicodes refer the website https://unicodelookup.com (or) https://unicode-table.com

**Local Converter using Python:**

**Reference:** conversion of password "p@s#w:E" to unicode will be as follows,

```
@ = %40
$ = %24
# = %23
: = %3A
p@s#w:E = p%40s%23w%3AE
```

**Input:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# python -c "import sys, urllib as enc; print enc.quote_plus(sys.argv[1])" "p@s#w:E"
```

**Output:**

```
p%40s%23w%3AE
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your username is `foo` and your password is `bar$`.

Quote them:

```
http_proxy='http://foo:bar$@localhost:3128/' wget http://www.google.com/
```

Or escape them:

```
http_proxy=http://foo:bar\$@localhost:3128/ wget http://www.google.com/
```

What if your password is `bar/`? URL encode them.

```
http_proxy="http://foo:bar%2F@localhost:3128/" wget http://www.google.com/
```