# How do I set http_proxy and https_proxy with the username and password with it in Linux?

Tags: linux, proxy, http, http-proxy

I know it is pretty straightforward to use/export **http_proxy** and **https_proxy** in any Linux variant but, when it becomes tricky if we want to use with authentication like below,

I have test this it is works fine with curl directly without http_proxy or https_proxy on,

```
unset http_proxy; curl -x http://proxy-abc-xyz.com:8080 --proxy-user iam@abc-xyz.com -L http://www.yahoo.com
```

Above command asks for the password :

I enter it on the screen, the page loads up, which is completely fine.

My Password is something like this :

> A@CDe2022@@@

But when I try with simple export command, I couldn't able to make it work,

```
export http_proxy="http://iam@abc-xyz.com:A@CDe2022@@@@proxy-abc-xyz.com:8080"
export https_proxy="http://iam@abc-xyz.com:A@CDe2022@@@@proxy-abc-xyz.com:8080"
```

Three @@@'s are in password the next one is for the domain.

But the above is not working somehow.

When I try with `curl -v https://www.google.com` the command just stalls there no output at all, it tries to connect but it is not able to get through.

Could someone help with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [special characters in http\_proxy environment variable](https://serverfault.com/questions/479178/special-characters-in-http-proxy-environment-variable)

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov thanks for the update, it does makes sense but, even after using the encoding it doesn't work for me.

But the same proxy works this way,

`curl -x http://proxy-abc-xyz.com:8080 --proxy-user iam@abc-xyz.com:<password> -L http://www.yahoo.com`


I get the below output using curl when I export the proxy with **http_proxy, https_proxy, HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, NO_PROXY, and no_proxy**.

`curl -v www.google.com

* About to connect() to proxy abc-xyz.com port 0 (#0)
*   Trying <ip-address>...`

It stalls here.

Tried both ways like encoding the URL & password way

Comment: You hand't encoded the symbol '@', did you? So it thought the the host name to connect to is after the first '@', that is, in the username — abc-xyz.com, and then the port is after ':' is not integer and it was understood as "0". Encoded `iam@abc-xyz.com` will look like `iam%40abc-xyz.com`, `A@CDe2022@@@` is encoded as `A%40CDe2022%40%40%40`, and the whole thing needs to look like `http://iam%40abc-xyz.com:A%40CDe2022%40%40%40@proxy-abc-xyz.com:8080`. Notice there is only a single '@' character here, and it is after the password. There is no '@' in username or in password - it is urlencoded.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs again! encoding worked but it is able to recognise the password but I have got the below thingy in CURL, which doesn't mean the authentication is successful.

`* Proxy auth using Basic with user 'iam@abc-xyz.com:A@CDe2022@@@'
> CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.google.com:443
> Proxy-Authorization: Basic cmFtY
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy **Authentication Required**
< Proxy-Authenticate: NEGOTIATE
< Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
< Proxy-Authenticate: BASIC realm="ntlm"`

Comment: I have managed to make it work with cntlm in Linux however, I having SSL Verify Failed issue with that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

export http_proxy="http://userName:yourPassword@yourProxyURL.com:8080"
export https_proxy="http://userName:yourPassword@yourProxyURL.com:8080"

CAVEAT: Some app need to have the http_proxy`s variable in capital. So I suggess you use both set. Lower case ans capital case.

export http_proxy and https_proxy as well as HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY

Also, this is verrry usefull..

NO_PROXY=    and also.
no_proxy=

Comment: Thanks for the update, it does makes sense but, even after using the encoding it doesn't work for me.

But the same proxy works this way,

`curl -x http://proxy-abc-xyz.com:8080 --proxy-user iam@abc-xyz.com:<password> -L http://www.yahoo.com`


I get the below output using curl when I export the proxy with **http_proxy, https_proxy, HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, NO_PROXY, and no_proxy**.

`curl -v www.google.com

* About to connect() to proxy abc-xyz.com port 0 (#0)
*   Trying <ip-address>...`

It stalls here.

Tried both ways like encoding the URL & password way

Comment: May be like this:   http_proxy="http://'domain\user':'password':proxyUrl.com:8080"